# how to parse milliseconds into date in javascript

Tags: javascript, date

i am getting stucked to convert date from ms (receiving from json)
i was recieving the date in json in format below

`/Date(1355250600000)/`

so that i converted it into ms --->

```
var d = response.ContributionsDate.replace("/", "").replace("/", "").replace("Date(", "").replace(")", "");
```

so now its `d = 1355250600000`

to convert i tried the code below--->

```
            var date = new Date(d);
            alert(date);
```

but did not work (`invalid date`), if anyone have any idea about date parsing, help me

Comment: ques updated, take a look once more...

Comment: What date should it represent?  That timestamp could be Tue, 11 Dec 2012 18:30:00 GMT.

Comment: format it into MM-dd-yyyy...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/formatting-a-date-in-javascript

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`d` is a string, not a number.

Try

```
var date = new Date(+d);
```

instead.

The prefix `+` causes coercion to a number.

Incidentally, you can simplify your replace operations to

```
var d = +response.ContributionsDate.match(/^\/Date\((\d+)\)\/$/)[0];
```

Comment: thanks @Mike Samuel, its working now, one more thing. how to format it into `MM-dd-yyyy` ?